# Jetpack Compose CircularProgressIndicator not spinning during loading state

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have states for the UI based on the return of the network response. The network states are Success and Failure. The UI has Three states Success, Loading and Error. During the Loading State I want to show a Circular Progress indicator. On the emulator it works fine, it spins during loading state. When I ran the same test on a physical device the progress indicator was not spinning.
This is inside the view model

```
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<HomeUIState>(HomeUIState.Loading)
        val uiState: StateFlow<HomeUIState> = _uiState

fun postData(data: String){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            when(val result = apiService.postData( data= data)) {
                is NetworkResponse.Success -> {
                    Log.d("DataViewModel", "postData: Success")
                   _uiState.value = HomeUIState.Success


                }

                is NetworkResponse.Failure -> {
                    Log.d("DataViewModel", "postData: Failure")
                 
                    _uiState.value = HomeUIState.Error(errorMessage = result.error.toString(), showError = true)



                }
            }
        }
    }

    sealed interface HomeUIState {
        data object Success : HomeUIState
        data class Error(val errorMessage: String, val showError: Boolean = false) : HomeUIState
        data object Loading : HomeUIState
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The default dispatcher for `viewModelScope.launch`, is the Main dispatcher.  Try it with a specified dispatcher, which will execute the network work on another thread.

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){...}
```

Comment: For a production codebase, you will want to pass in the Dispatcher for testing reasons.  https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#inject-dispatchers

Comment: So I changed it to Dispatcher IO but it still does not spin in the loading state.

Comment: If you remove all executing code from the ```launch``` and just update the state to show the spinner, does it spin on the device?

Comment: After removing the code from the launch block, the spinner still does not spin

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a coroutine issue. I commented out code in the view model so that when navigating to the screen its only state is loading and the spinner still doesn't spin. I'm trying to see whats blocking the UI thread but i dont know how to read the profiler for the CPU.